# How to use a single conditional statement while streaming a Set<String>

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Set<String> allNames`. I am creating a new Set by applying some filtering.

```java
Set<String> allNames = Set.of(
    "Alex",
    "Joseph",
    "Mark",
    "John",
    "Peter",
    "Joe",
    "Adam",
    "Harry",
    "Jacob",
    "Alan"
);
Set<String> filteredSet = allNames.stream()
    .filter(name -> names.startsWith("Jo")
    .collect(toSet());
```

I have another `Set<String> thirdPartySet` coming from some API call. I want to check if this thirdPartySet is null then filtered out the names which are starting from `Al` otherwise keep them.

I tried to use `filter(x -> thirdPartySet == null ? !x.startsWith("Al"))` but since it's a ternary operator it is asking an else conditon. Is there any way I can achieve `if condition` while streaming?

Comment: `.filter(x -> thirdPartySet != null || !x.startWith("Al"))`?

Comment: Or add an "else true" to the ternary: `filter(x -> thirdPartySet == null ? !x.startsWith("Al") : true)`. But what exactly is the purpose of `thirdPartySet`? Are those the prefixes to be filtered out?

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you it works! actually it contains some kind of results and if it is null then I need to remove few names from filtered set

Answer (score 1):

If thirdPartySet is null, check if x doesn't start with "Al":

```java
filter(x -> thirdPartySet != null || !x.startsWith("Al"))
```

You asked about an if:

```java
filter(x -> {
    if (thirdPartySet == null) {
        return !x.startsWith("Al");
    }
    return true;
})
```

Comment: This will remove all elements if `thirdPartySet` is not null. As I understand the question, OP wants to _keep_ all elements in that case, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, but, the condition is trivially modified to behave that way. The general notion is: Don't use a ternary, use && or ||.

Comment: @rzwitserloot actually, this is a case where a ternary has a point; since the `thirdPartySet == null` condition does not change during the Stream operation, it’s not necessary to test it for every element. So `.filter(thirdPartySet == null? x -> true: x -> !x.startsWith("Al"))` tests the `thirdPartySet == null` condition only once.